# how to get database from development to production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano

What is the best way to dump my development database structure and deploy it to a production server?

Im using capistrano deployment for rails app

- how would one migrate changes in development database structure automatic with each cap deploy?

Comment: Are you not using migrations?

Comment: I use migrations but removed them at some points and did a scheme dump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a migration that executes your schema dump. Then use migrations to make changes after that.

Then, you'll execute `cap deploy:migrations` to deploy your code and run your migrations.

Comment: how would i add a migration that executres a schema dump? I understand the principe but no idea how to write that thx!

Comment: Ok I pasted schema.rb from local machine to schema.rb on production and that seemed to work. The production schema.rb was empty I suspected it to be copied from my local git repo to prod.

Comment: Check out rake schema:dump to get it into a file